# Libreoffice vs Lotus Symphony vs Starroffice. What is better?

Tags: software-recommendation

I know that all three mentioned office apps are based on OpenOffice.org . I previously used Libreoffice but I had troubles with editing PDFs and importing/exproting MS Office documents sometimes. I know that StarrOffice can edit it (I haven't tested it) but Starr is not developing now and it's quiet old. I haven't used Lotus Symphony and I'm wondering if it can edit PDFs and how compactible is it with MS Office
Could anyone please help me to make a choise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lotus Symphony as well as Star Office are discontinued, so LibreOffice is a clear winner here, surpassing even OpenOffice it has been forked from.

Long story short - Lotus Symphony and Star Office were either legacy or not so actively developed software while OpenOffice remained the main player. Then a group of former OpenOffice developers along with new newly recruited developers forked OpenOffice and called their project LibreOffice. Funny thing is within a year LibreOffice team has done more improvements within a year than OpenOffice has in 5 years and it still keeps the high development/code cleanup pace.